# Need help. i want to embed a web page with a flash presentation in a wordpress page

Tags: wordpress, flash, embed

Here is the link of the webpage with flash presentation:

http://services.google.com/analytics/breeze/en/v5/interface_navigation_v15_ad1/.

Now i created a page  in wordpress and i want to embed that video in the page i created, is it possible? Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use an [**`IFRAME`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/iframe).

It's better to embed this kind of HTML as a Shortcode, like `[embed_html src="http://example.com"]`:

```
add_shortcode( 'embed_iframe', 'shortcode_so_14766891' );

/**
 * Example usage
 * [embed_html src="http://site.com" width="400" height="400"]Iframes not enabled[embed_html]
 */
function shortcode_so_14766891( $atts, $content = '' ) 
{
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
            'url'      => null,
            'width'    => '100%',
            'height'   => '500',
        ), $atts ));

    // URL not provided, bail out
    if( !$url )
        return;

    $html = "<iframe id='myFrame' src='$url' width='$width' height='$height'>$content</iframe>";

    return $html;       
}
```